# Why is the contract output in the truffle console different from the output in JS?

Tags: solidity, truffle

The simplified contract looks like this：

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract WeLink{

    mapping(address=>string[]) public messageURLs;
    function publish(string calldata message) public {
        messageURLs[msg.sender].push(message);
    }
    function getmessages(address addr) external view returns (string[] memory) {
        return messageURLs[addr];
    }
}
```

When I call the contract method in the truffle console, it prints the output correctly. I use the command `WeLink.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.getmessages('0xdD32c67C4351E882C6Ba4eBeFc0e7AF7bD82fBCE')});`. Then I can get the right output.
[image]
However, when I use the same code in JS, it prints the different output which is strange.
[image]

It looks like the output is truncated. Why ?

The code in JS like blew shows.
[image]

Comment: is this the full contract code. you dont have setMessages function?

Comment: It has the function but I just omit.